Laravel powergrid Livewire styles not loading
I just created a fresh Laravel project using Laravel Breeze auth from scratch. I recently installed livewire-powergrid package to create my first DataTable. I followed the instructions, but when I show my DataTable, it looks like some CSS is missing.
This is my config:
resources/js/app.js
import './bootstrap';
import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
import './../../vendor/power-components/livewire-powergrid/dist/powergrid';
import './../../vendor/power-components/livewire-powergrid/dist/tailwind.css';

resources/css/app.css
@import "../../node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


Img here:

I hope you can help me.
Show grid with powergrid styles by default (using tailwindcss)

PowerGrid is in VueJS therefore you need to run nodeJS to make the render work and in the view where you present it you must put the @powerGridStyles directives before and after the body tag
